# Akka remote routees in scalable cluster

Tags: scala, cluster-computing, akka, scalability

I have an application that I want to scale so in one instance (master) I create router (created periodically depending on requests):

```
val executors = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[ExecutorWorker], nq).withRouter(
ClusterRouterConfig(ConsistentHashingRouter(), ClusterRouterSettings(
  maxInstancesPerNode = 10,
  allowLocalRoutees = true, useRole = Some("notifier")))),
name = "router")
```

If I now register new instance (other server) in cluseter with role "notifier" would the new router actors be created also in this new instance heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you might have to define `totalInstances = 1000` in the ClusterRouterSettings.